# Declaring a map in a separate file and reading its contents

Tags: rust

I'm trying to declare a map in a separate file, and then access it from my main function.

I want Rust's equivalent (or whatever comes closest) to this C++ map:

```
static const std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> table = {
    { "a", { "foo" } },
    { "e", { "bar", "baz" } }
};
```

This is my attempt in Rust.

table.rs

```
use std::container::Map;

pub static table: &'static Map<~str, ~[~str]> = (~[
    (~"a", ~[~"foo"]), 
    (~"e", ~[~"bar", ~"baz"])
]).move_iter().collect();
```

main.rs

```
mod table;

fn main() {
    println(fmt!("%?", table::table));
}
```

The above gives two compiler errors in table.rs, saying "constant contains unimplemented expression type".

I also have the feeling that the map declaration is less than optimal for the purpose.

Finally, I'm using Rust 0.8.

Comment: At present, Rust only supports literals in statics; there is no function evaluation, which is what `.move_iter().collect()` is, and there is no feature equivalent to the "initializer list" construction that I believe that to be (I don't know much C++, but simple examination of std::map docs suggest that's what that construct would be).

Comment: Another technique you can use is not using a `Map<~str, ~[~str]>` but instead using a `&'static [(&'static str, &'static [&'static str])]`. (You can't do owned pointers in statics either, by the way.) That way you can have a valid literal like `[("a", ["foo"]), ("e", ["bar", "baz"])]`.

Answer (score 1):

As Chris Morgan noted, rust doesn't allow you to run user code in order to initialize global variables before `main` is entered, unlike C++. So you are mostly limited to primitive types that you can initialize with literal expressions. This is, afaik, part of the design and unlikely to change, even though the particular error message is probably not final.

Depending on your use case, you might want to change your code so you're manually passing your map as an argument to all the functions that will want to use it (ugh!), use [task-local storage](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/0.8/std/local_data/index.html) to initialize a tls slot with your map early on and then refer to it later in the same task (ugh?), or use unsafe code and a `static mut` variable to do much the same with your map wrapped in an `Option` maybe so it can start its life as `None` (*ugh!*).

Comment: (Note that the `static mut` may require an unsafe pointer too, because `HashMap` has a destructor (for cleaning up its elements and its allocated memory), and destructors in `static`s are not supported; i.e. `static mut HASHMAP: *HashMap<~str, ~[~str]> = 0 as *HashMap<~str, ~[~str]>; fn get_hashmap() -> &'static HashMap<...> { unsafe { if HASHMAP.is_null() { <initialise> } std::cast::transmute(HASHMAP) } }`; this is *extremely* un-thread-safe; and the initialisation should be done by transmuting a `~HashMap<...>` to a `*HashMap<...>`.)